# python dictionary combining based on common element

Tags: python

I have python list of dictionary like

````
# Input
data = [{'name':'a','val1':23},{'name':'a','val2':45},{'name':'a','val4':'56'},{'name':'b','val10':12},{'name':'b','val45':45},{'name':'b','val100':23}]```
````

How to flatten above dictionary to below format.

## Expected Result

````
[{'name':'a','val1':23,'val2':45,'val4':56},{'name':'b','val10':12,'val45':45,'val100':23}]```
````

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: need to visualize [{'name':'a','val1':23},{'name':'a','val2':45} this data not supported reactjs multiline chart. so am trying to convert [{'name':'a','val1':23,'val2':45,'val4':56}, this form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. find same `name` dict, if it in `result`, then update it, else create it.
2. convert format to your desired format.

#### code:

```
datas = [{'name':'a','val1':23},{'name':'a','val2':45},{'name':'a','val4':'56'},{'name':'b','val10':12},{'name':'b','val45':45},{'name':'b','val100':23}]
result = {}
for data in datas:
    key = data["name"]
    data.pop("name")
    if key in result:
        result[key].update(data)
    else:
        result[key] = data
ans = []
for name,val in result.items():
    temp = {"name":name}
    for k,v in val.items():
        temp.update({k:v})
    ans.append(temp)
print(ans)
```

#### result:

```
[
    {"name": "a", "val1": 23, "val2": 45, "val4": "56"},
    {"name": "b", "val10": 12, "val45": 45, "val100": 23},
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [`itertools.groupby` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
import itertools

data = [{'name': 'a', 'val1': 23},
 {'name': 'a', 'val2': 45},
 {'name': 'a', 'val4': '56'},
 {'name': 'b', 'val10': 12},
 {'name': 'b', 'val45': 45},
 {'name': 'b', 'val100': 23}]
 
results = []
for _, values in itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x['name']):
    results.append({k: v for value in values for k, v in value.items()})
    
print(results)
```

Outputs

```
[{'name': 'a', 'val1': 23, 'val2': 45, 'val4': '56'},
 {'name': 'b', 'val10': 12, 'val100': 23, 'val45': 45}]
```

---

Note that the above will only work if your `data` is ordered by name, [as @jizhihaoSAMA noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569608/python-dictionary-combining-based-on-common-element/68569748#comment121182084_68569748). If it's not, you can just do

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
```

before applying this method.

Comment: You may need to sort them firstly to make sure it is ordered.